# How to draw bullet in table views cell?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, ios4

I want to draw bullet in my table views cell.

I found one method for getting bullet is :

```
 lbl.text = @"\u2022 Hey its bullet";
```

But it is giving small bullet.

So is there any other way to get bullet in my apps?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the bullet is small it's because that the standard size for the font-family/font-size you are using.

You'd have to set the bullet font to a different font family or font size to increase it's size.

I assume you're using a default cell view. You could create a custom cell view and manually place a bullet in interface builder with a UILabel after it.

Answer (score 2):

You could try adding an image to the imageView property of your tableviewcell. Something like this:

```
myCell.imageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"myBulletPoint.png"];
```

You'd probably want to cache the image, but this should get you going.